# Use merge,the error message is There is an incorrect syntax near the keyword 'into'

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I use merge like this:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
    merge into TD_1 tar
    using (select Title,AnnouncementID,SupplyTitle,EmployeeCode,registered,modified from TSupply_2 ) source
    on (tar.SupplyTitle=source.SupplyTitle and tar.EmployeeCode=source.EmployeeCode) 
    when matched then update set tar.modified=getdate()
    when not matched then
    insert (Title,AnnouncementID,SupplyTitle,EmployeeCode,registered,modified) 
    values(source.Title,source.AnnouncementID,source.SupplyTitle,source.EmployeeCode,getdate(),getdate());
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

But the error is:

> There is an incorrect syntax near the keyword 'into'.
>
> There is an incorrect syntax near 'source'.

How can I fix it?

Comment: What happens when you click on the error in the message pane, it will tell you which line has the issue

Comment: Are you sure you're actually running this code against a 2008 (or later) server? I seem to remember the error message was non-obvious and didn't point at `merge` specifically if you tried to use in on 2000/2005 servers. But it's been a while since I saw the error and can't remember if it would look like this specifically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I know where is wrong,the `COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL` is 80 in my database.
So I can't use `merge`.

My database version is `Microsoft SQL Server 2008`
Then I modified `COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL`:

```
ALTER DATABASE DB1
SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 100
```

Then there is no error message.

Answer (score 1):

The Merge Syntax:

```
MERGE <target_table> [AS TARGET]
USING <table_source> [AS SOURCE]
ON <search_condition>
[WHEN MATCHED 
THEN <merge_matched> ]
[WHEN NOT MATCHED [BY TARGET]
THEN <merge_not_matched> ]
[WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE
THEN <merge_matched> ];
```

But you are using `into`:

```
merge into TD_1 tar
```

Also `source` is a reserved word of SQL. You can replace it if you want.

Try to take a look at this [tutorial](https://www.essentialsql.com/introduction-merge-statement/).

Comment: I has modified my code to `menge`,I delete `into`,but the error still exists.

Comment: Be careful to your `<target_table>` and `<source_table>`.

Comment: Try to change your `TD_1` as yourTableTarget.

Comment: Question is tagged SQL Server and it least for that product, `INTO` is a valid optional keyword in the [MERGE syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#syntax)

Comment: And `source` isn't a [reserved keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)